# Error while importing shapefile to PostGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I'm trying to import ArcGIS shapefile to PostGIS. I get an error like this:

[image: error]

My client and server encoding both of them "UTF-8"

[image]

[image]

I get an error especially in the point type.

How can I fix it?

[image]

I tried Latin1 and Latin3 but did not work.

[image]

Comment: do you have qgis? you should try and import this file through there too see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that your shapefile's DBF character encoding is not UTF-8. By default shp2pgsql-gui assumes the incoming encoding is UTF-8 so if there is a mismatch here the tool will fail.

You need to ensure that the DBF file character encoding (accessed through the Options menu of shp2pgsql-gui) matches that of your shapefile.

[image]

If you don't know what the DBF encoding is and UTF-8 hasn't worked, it's worth trying LATIN-1.

Comment: Hey Ali, thank you for your answer. I tried LATIN1 and LATIN3 but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Umut Okay, could be Windows-1252

Comment: @Umut Also, you can avoid the guesswork if you have a .cpg file along with the standard shapefile components as this will give you information about the character encoding.